# How to sort a file with multiple delimiters?

Tags: sort, whitespace

Listing the available patches in openSUSE results in the following output.

The command that results int the details below is `zypper patches`. The same result is also displayed when running the command `zypper list-patches -a`

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Repository                        | Name               | Category    | Severity  | Interactive | Status     | Summary                                                                                           
----------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1000 | recommended | moderate  | ---         | not needed | Recommended update for gnuhealth, proteus, tryton, trytond, trytond_purchase, trytond_stock_supply
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1004 | security    | low       | ---         | not needed | Security update for ffmpeg-4                                                                      
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1005 | security    | moderate  | ---         | not needed | Security update for chromium                                                                      
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1006 | security    | moderate  | ---         | applied    | Security update for okular                                                                        
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1007 | recommended | moderate  | ---         | applied    | Recommended update for tigervnc
```

In an attempt to sort "Status" using the command `sort -k 6,6 listing.txt | less` for example yields the following output.

```
----------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Non-Oss | openSUSE-2018-1082 | recommended | moderate  | ---         | not needed | Security update for opera                                                                         
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Non-Oss | openSUSE-2018-1240 | recommended | moderate  | ---         | not needed | Recommended update for opera                                                                      
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Non-Oss | openSUSE-2018-1294 | recommended | low       | ---         | not needed | Recommended update for Regina-REXX, THE, ooRexx                                                   
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1000 | recommended | moderate  | ---         | not needed | Recommended update for gnuhealth, proteus, tryton, trytond, trytond_purchase, trytond_stock_supply
openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update         | openSUSE-2018-1007 | recommended | moderate  | ---         | applied    | Recommended update for tigervnc    
Repository                        | Name               | Category    | Severity  | Interactive | Status     | Summary
```

In checking if the delimiter is a combination of spaces and tabs using the syntax highlighting rules in vim, it returns only spaces.

```
:syntax on
:set syntax=whitespace
```

[image]

It seems that the file may using multiple delimiters.

- What is the most effective way of determining the delimiters in use?
- What would be the best and simplest way to sort the columns based on the delimiters in use?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - I updated the question with the commands that return the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do, unless you want to keep the header in place:

```
tail -n +5 listing.txt | sort -b -k6 -t'|'
```

You can omit the `-b` option of `sort` ("ignore leading blanks) if the file is using white space regularly (ie. it doesn't mix `| applied` and `|    applied`).

But I guess that a) that program probably has some options to tweak its format into something more machine-readable b) you'll be better off with just eg. `awk -F'|' '$6~/not needed/'` instead of `sort`.

Comment: It's probably best not to assume there are 5 patches every single time.

Comment: @NikoGambt `tail +5` is not the same as `tail -5`

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Comment: @mosvy - Interestingly the command `tail +5` results in output `tail: cannot open '+5' for reading: No such file or directory`. How did you determine that the only delimiter concerned is `|`?

Comment: @Motivated corrected to a standard-compliant `tail` syntax. You can also use `sed -n '5,$p'` instead of `tail -n +5`. If you're using `sort -k6,6` without a `-t` option, it will consider the 3rd `|` as the 6th field.

Comment: @mosvy - How did you determine that `|` was the only delimiter though? For example, how did you distinguish between the use of spaces, tabs or any other delimiter?

Comment: @Motivated You don't have to distinguish between spaces and tabs; the `-b` option of `sort` should cause it to ignore any leading *blanks* in the selected field(s), no matter if they're spaces or tabs. If you're concerned about the file containing nulls and other non-printable chars, you could check it with `hexdump` ;-)

Comment: @Motivated a simple way to make tabs and other "frog" characters visible is with the much maligned `-t` option of `cat`: `cat -t your_file`

Comment: @Motivated anyways, if you're about something like "how to do some complex sorting with sort(1), as with perl's `sort {...}`" (ie. use regexps as delimiters, do some drastic normalization on the line without affecting the output, etc) then a) I don't think that's possible b) the example is very badly chosen.

Comment: @mosvy - The command `cat -t list.txt` doesn't yield a different output to `cat list.txt`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88566/discussion-between-motivated-and-mosvy).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
awk 'NR<=4 {print $0; next } { print $0 | "sort -k6,6 -t\\|" }' listing.txt
```

It runs `awk` on `listing.txt`; instead you could pipe the data into `awk` (leaving out the `listing.txt` at the end, of course). The `awk`-script prints the first four header lines as they are. The rest of the lines is piped into `sort`. `Sort` sorts the 6th column, identifying it using a delimiter equal to the pipe symbol.